# Overload "cin" for a and new arbitrary floating number

Tags: c++

I want to overload input operator in c++ so that i can replace the input correctly in the new type, i have the following

```
struct{
           uint64_t frac;
           unit64_t exp;

  };
```

i want what appears after the float point in frac and before it in exp.

any Help please !

Comment: I didn't get. An example please ?

Comment: What's the problem you are encountering?

Comment: basically if a user enters 132.3232, the >> will need to automatically put 132 in frac and 3232 in exp.

Comment: Do you really have a requirement that this code not compile on a system that doesn't have an exact 64-bit unsigned type? `uint_fast64_t` would probably be better, as would `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @Pepe No it won't. Streams won't ignore the `.`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think that's what he wants to do I didn't say the stream will ignore the .

Comment: You need to define the scaling factor for `frac`. Inputs of `1.23` and `1.230` should both give the same result. Inputs of `4.56` and `4.056` should give different results -- and the `056` should not be interpreted as octal. (That's assuming you actually want to treat the input as a string that could represent a real number in decimal notation. If you want some other odd input format, you need to define it and explain it in the question.)

Comment: @KeithThompson You are correct. I didn't handle that in my answer. Come to think of it, this is kind of a low quality question since OP actually wanted to create their own Big number class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a string to input number and then fill your `struct` elements by overloading `<<` operator :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 struct Frac {
           unsigned long  frac; //uint64_t
           unsigned long exp;  //uint64_t
   friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, Frac &f)
   {
      std::string s;
      is >> s;
      std::size_t n = s.find(".");

      if (n != std::string::npos)
      {
         f.frac = std::atoll(s.substr(0,n).c_str());
         f.exp = std::atoll(s.substr(n+1).c_str());
      }
      else
      {
         f.frac = std::atoll(s.c_str());
         f.exp  = 0 ;
      }
   }
};

int main()
{
  Frac f;

  std::cin>>f;

  std::cout << f.frac <<" "<< f.exp;
}
```

See [HERE](http://ideone.com/7AkRs6)

**Edit :**

The above will give same results for inputs like 1.23, 1.230, and 1.023
because the `struct` is defined in that way as per the current question.

faction element should be of type `double` or `float` and then `std::atof` can be used

Comment: Does this give sensible results for `1.23`, `1.230`, and `1.023`?

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah no, but that's question flaw

Comment: If you recognize a flaw in the question, I suggest that you should point it out.

Comment: If the fraction is of type `double`, then you might as well forget the struct and use `double` to hold the number.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this

```
struct Number               //Changed this because I don't know what you are looking for
{
    int frac;
    double exp;
};


istream& operator>>(istream& in, Number& number)
{
    double temp;
    in >> temp;
    number.frac = (int)temp;             //You need to calculate frac here not sure what you are looking for
    number.exp = temp - number.frac;     //Same for exp
    return in;
}
```

Comment: thank u, but how i do that if i had frac divided in two parts , for example struct {uint64_t exp;   uint32_t frac1; uint32_t frac2; };

Comment: Can you give me an example input? I'm not really sure what you mean by frac and exp.

Comment: no no input is just a float, but what i meant is that i decided to make the fraction part 96bit and the best way i thought of is to divide frac into 3 part frac1, frac2, frac3 so how would i then assign what i get from the user into these frac's

Comment: @user3038489: When you say the input is a float, do you really mean that it's a string that could represent a floating-point value? If the input is really a value of type `float`, that's not clear from your question.

Comment: @user3038489 well that's a whole different question my friend and would require a lot more handling.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know how stream input for user defined types is implemented and you're asking for that info rather than asking for somebody to just write a custom input function for you:

To overload the input operation for your own types you simply provide a non-member `operator>>` with a compatible signature in the same namespace where your type is defined.

```
struct S {int i}; // type to read from input stream

std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is, S &s) {
  // read from stream
  int i;
  is >> i;
  // check for errors, validate stream input, etc.
  // ...

  // return the input stream
  return i;
}

int main() {
    S s;
    std::cin >> s;
}
```

Often `operator >>` needs access to private members of the type. You can declare the operator to be a friend. And in fact you can define the non-member `operator >>` at the same time and it will get put in the right namespace:

```
class C {
  int i;

  friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is, S &s) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Comment: as an alternative to the friend you can define a read(std::istream &in) member function then in the operator>>(std::istream in, S &s)  you call read on s and pass it in ie.  s.read(in); and read does all the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class Elem, class Tr>
std::basic_istream<Elem, Tr>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<Elem, Tr>& str,
    Number num) {
    char ch;
    return str >> num.exp >> ch >> num.frac;
}
```

However, this is a somewhat peculiar input format. Usually digits to the left of the decimal point are part of the fraction, and the number of those digits is used to adjust the exponent.

Comment: Maybe that's what he meant for the variables to mean.

Comment: Don't you mean that digits to the *right* of the decimal point are part of the fraction?

Comment: @KeithThompson - no, I mean what I said: ordinarily digits to the left of the decimal point are part of the fraction, not, as specified in the question, part of the exponent. Using base 10, .111 has a fraction of .111 and an exponent of 0; 1.11 has a fraction of .111 and an exponent of 1.